# What type of wires are used inside a USB 3.0?

Tags: usb, cables, wire

In a USB 3.0 cable, there are 9 different wires used. In the same, suppose we take the two differential pair wires (TX, RX) are used, which are in the range of 26-34 gauge. But I need to know what type of wire is used exactly inside? If I need to place an order what should I enter?

Thanks in advance,

Saurabh

Comment: USB 3 needs carefully impedance controlled wires, it's not as easy as ordering some AWG number. What do you intend to do?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, 
I have a USB 3.0 interface on my board where I can suggest the exact type of wires to be used for each signal, especially for the differential signals in my document.

Comment: I guess the USB specification provides you with the mandatory parameters for the transmission lines + Power Supply... https://www.usb.org/document-library/usb-type-cr-cable-and-connector-specification-revision-21 (just peeking into it: yes there are detailed specifications!)

Comment: Thanks, the spec helped!

Answer (score 1):

USB 3.0 cables are both common and specialized enough that you can directly search for that, and/or in a parametric search, select "2 pair + 4" as the desired number of conductors.

Comment: Thanks will look into it.